# How do you increase the max number of concurrent connections in Apache?

Tags: apache

What httpd conf settings do I need to change to increase the max number of concurrent connections for Apache? NOTE: I turned off KeepAlive since this is mainly an API server.

```
#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive Off

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 187):

Here's a detailed explanation about the calculation of MaxClients and MaxRequestsPerChild

http://web.archive.org/web/20160415001028/http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache

```
ServerLimit 16
StartServers 2
MaxClients 200
MinSpareThreads 25
MaxSpareThreads 75
ThreadsPerChild 25
```

First of all, whenever an apache is started, it will start 2 child processes which is determined by `StartServers` parameter. Then each process will start 25 threads determined by `ThreadsPerChild` parameter so this means 2 process can service only 50 concurrent connections/clients i.e. 25x2=50. Now if more concurrent users comes, then another child process will start, that can service another 25 users. But how many child processes can be started is controlled by `ServerLimit` parameter, this means that in the configuration above, I can have 16 child processes in total, with each child process can handle 25 thread, in total handling 16x25=400 concurrent users. But if number defined in `MaxClients` is less which is 200 here, then this means that after 8 child processes, no extra process will start since we have defined an upper cap of `MaxClients`. This also means that if I set `MaxClients` to 1000, after 16 child processes and 400 connections, no extra process will start and we cannot service more than 400 concurrent clients even if we have increase the `MaxClient` parameter. In this case, we need to also increase `ServerLimit` to 1000/25 i.e. `MaxClients/ThreadsPerChild=40`
So this is the optmized configuration to server 1000 clients

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          40
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There seem to be some changes after version 2.3.13. For example MaxClients is now MaxRequestWorkers.

Comment: Please advise: the site linked is currently serving malware (and porn)... It's probably hacked... Quite anoying if you are at work searching for a solution on stackoverflow and a full blown porn site opens... https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.genericarticles.com

Comment: Okay, but what is the memory required and CPU requirements for this optimal config. Or how do i take in the consideration of CPU and Memory also for this optimizations.

Comment: I applied this configuration and still the current connections are reached...seems like a hard limit somewhere else

Comment: This link https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly may help when setting the directives in order to achieve acceptable result. I myself am still learning from the article, though.

Answer (score 11):

change the MaxClients directive. the default is usually 256.

Comment: Here are the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#maxclients