# Web Server to serve maximum concurrent requests

Tags: tomcat, webserver, jetty

We are making HTTP Rest API server in which we want it to serve about 300K concurrent requests. What are the good web servers which we can use for this purpose? Some information about their limits on no. of concurrent requests would be great.

Comment: To handle 300k concurrent requests requires more work on the server hardware setup than it does the software choices.  Also, this is not a programming question, this question is better suited for other stackexchange sites like ServerFault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to work on the server's hardware as well as load balancing and auto scaling.
Cloud computing will be a very good solution for such a large concurrent request handling.
Else you'll need to handle the following things for sure.

- Stable internet connection with the very high upload and download link.
- High computing hardware (Multi-core processors, RAMs, RAID)
- Hassle of regular backup
- CDN
- Adding more server in the queue to handle the peek hours/days.
- many more
  Otherwise, you play around with the following variables in apache server. No matter whatever is the server, you'll need to these kind of variables to entertain your users.

  StartServers             5
  MinSpareServers          5
  MaxSpareServers         10
  MaxRequestWorkers      150
  MaxConnectionsPerChild   0

> [How do you increase the max number of concurrent connections in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, we have 10 machines on which we will run our server. So, it will be like we want about 30K requests on each machine. We were earlier using Dropwizard Framework for this which at max can handle only 1024 requests. So, can you suggest some good servers which are normally used for scaling such amount of concurrent requests.

Comment: I don't think so that apache can handle such number of concurrent users for a single server.
For now, I think you should give a try to load balancer along with the auto scaling of servers. Might be virtual server not the physical machines.