# Apache maximum requests per client per interval?

Tags: apache, http

I got a tool which is polling 10 http-requests in an 5 sec interval to an apache webserver. After some time the tool has problems to have all http requests being successfully served with the data. NetworkException.

Could it be that apache has a limit of maximum requests per client? in an interval? or an maximum volume or something? If so, is there a config parameter to change that?

sadly I can't give a better description of the exception because I am not the developer of the tool.

Many thanks for your help and best regards,
Mäfinho

Comment: Search StackOverflow for Apache max connections etc. 
For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache

Comment: I will check that. I generally searched on google and found bad resulsts also for stack overflow. Sorry if I was a little bit to unpatient there.