# how to limit connection to Apache server per client?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, download

When I download file from my Apache server with download applications like idm , wget or aria2c server only allow 8 connection to file to download now I need 32 connection to use maximum download speed.

How to config Apache server to serve 32 connection per client ?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far i know its clearly mentioned in the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376839/1154348),Do you need anything in addition like ipTable

```
  ServerLimit 16 
  StartServers 2
  MaxClients 200
  MinSpareThreads 25
  MaxSpareThreads 75
  ThreadsPerChild 25
```

Comment: I try set these setting but apache raise Invalid Command exception : `AH00526: Syntax error on line 226 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'MinSpareThreads', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.`