# How many connections can maintain a server and how to know it?

Tags: server

I am searching about how many connections can manage a server, I don't have any idea how to filter in google about it, even it would be fantastic if I could simulate an amount of queries and check by my self how many connections are possible

Thanks

Comment: Please, add more details. What server software you use, what language is your application written in, what type of application is it? Moreover, are you asking about number of connections or number of requests?

Comment: It all depends.

Comment: Well, the point is that I don't have anything specific, I just have to do a practice with the server and the language I want to use, I need to demostrate a method to show how many conections are posible in a server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe there are 6 available "pipes" when requesting resources from a server; such as, six images come through at a time to help populate a web page. However network speed ultimately determines efficiency of this. There are ways to increase the resources pulled by utilizing services such as Content Delivery Networks (CDN) to serve up only the images for example or a particular sub-domain to serve up query calls.

While the above may be out this scope, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache) regarding concurrent user connections to an Apache server and how to manage counts.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Im going to check the other answer.

Comment: This makes about as much sense to me as the question (i.e. none), yet the OP seems to understand whatever this is saying. I wonder what language they are speaking.

Comment: This answer assumes HTTP, and also assumes a compliant client (most clients can be tweaked to allow more simultaneous connections). It also does not cover how many individual clients can connect at once