# Do pending soap clients effect other user's performance in apache?

Tags: php, apache, performance, web-services, soap

If a web application has a slow soap web service integration for a page, would it effect other pages' performance? Would Apache continue processing other requests (from another clients) while waiting for an slow soap service?

p.s. I am already aware Apache spawn different processes for different connection as I observe from "top" command, but still I feel one client's SOAP pending effects another user.

Answer (score 2):

Apache will spawn another process to handle new requests. Unless there are something in the soap webservice that blocks on that end the requests should not block each other inside your webserver.

Comment: Up to like 200 or something, I forget ( maybe it was 100 ).  Been a long time sense I had that class.  Ah, 200. here is a good answer on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache

Comment: yes but if you hit the apache limit of to many worker processes it will give a "no resources" error page and not slow anything down. So i guess this is a different problem

Comment: Ok, I never hit that limit ( that I know of ) on any of my sites.  But we have a small list of clients only 250 that use our service.  So the chance of them all using it at the same time is very small.