# Configure apache server to handle only one request at time

Tags: php, multithreading, apache

As `apache` creates a new thread on new client request. so I wanted to configure apache to create an only single thread so it will not be able to handle more than one request at a time.

**What I have done**

Changes in apache `httpd-mpm.conf` `mpm_winnt_module` module

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        1
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Created a `block.php` which keep script sleep for 30 sec

```
<?php
    sleep(30);
    phpinfo();
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Created a `hello.php` which print hello

```
<?php
 echo "hello";
?>
```

Now what should be happening is when running `block.php` apache will create a new thread for it will take 30 sec to execute. In this 30sec the threads will busy.
At the same time, if I run `hello.php` it should not run because I have configured apache to create only one thread so `hello.php` should not be executed at the same time it should wait for 30sec.

But this is not working as I am thinking, is there anything I am missing? I just wanted to understand apache multithreading behavior.

Comment: Not sure if this is accurate but if you're using PHP FPM then there's a good chance the connection is established to the webserver but then delegated to the FPM manager so apache only keeps it for a short while.

Comment: Look at an answer [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache) and work in reverse. `MaxClients` looks important

Comment: @Scuzzy i have set configuration `<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit              1
    StartServers             1
    MinSpareThreads          1
    MaxSpareThreads          1 
    ThreadsPerChild          1
    MaxRequestWorkers        1
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
    MaxClients               1
</IfModule>` and now its working as expected thanks.