# Jmeter script works fine till 100 users and starts throwing "Socket Exception Error : Connection Closed" from 150 Users onwards

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, socketexception

Not sure if i am missing something. I am not entirely sure if the script is causing the issue as it runs fine till 100 concurrent users.

And the requirement is passing 450 Concurrent user test.

Need as much suggestions as possible. I'm a newbie to jmeter so i would like to do it in trial & error basis.

Answer (score 0):

Look into memory consumption and in properties file, you can change the Xmx limit and increase the heap size.

Also please mention what is the available Memory in the machine you are trying

Comment: Thanks for your answer. RAM - 5 GB, Heap Memory Allocation - 4 GB. Tried this fix but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting some form of a limit of the number of concurrently open connections, the limit can be:

1. On operating system level ([Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Search.94/ATGSearchAdmin/html/s1207adjustingtcpsettingsforheavyload01.html)/[Linux](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux))
2. On [application server or proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache) level

Among the other possible reasons are:

- JMeter may [lack resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and fail to open or keep opened a connection
- Application can just die and stop serving new requests

So use network monitoring tools on both JMeter and application under test side ([JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) is a good candidate) and make sure to inspect application and operating system logs as there too many possible reasons and one line of error message isn't enough to guess where the problem is.

Comment: Will try this and let u know. Thanks 

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I have tried your fix but its still not helping as i couldn't figure out where the problem is. Today, i tried running the test for 160 users for 1 hour, out of which only 93 users managed to run for the entire duration. Users are getting dropped due to the socket exception error. The load distribution on the server side is proper, CPU is hitting 100% usage but the application is responding properly while trying to navigate. So i'm really not sure where the problem is. Response code of 160 user test : https://imgur.com/a/pdmDPWG

Comment: However the 100 user test is running fine without errors. Response code of 100 user test: https://imgur.com/a/6va9IqU